# Java generics confusion

Tags: java, list, generics

I am a bit of confused about java generics

Here is the code

```
class Base{}

class Derived extends Base{}
```

WE can instantiate a list like this

```
List<? extends Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
```

Why cannot I add a a new item like this

```
list.add(new Base());
```

So user cannot use "add" method as far as a wildcard ? in the genetics type?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PECS - producer extends, consumer super.

If you replace `extends` with `super`, you can add `new Base()`.

`List<? extends Base>` means "a list that holds instances of any subclass of Base (or `Base` itself). But it cannot hold instances of two different subclasses.

If you want your list to hold `Base` and `Derived`, then use `List<Base>`. But note that it cannot be later cast to `List<Derived>`

Comment: That acronym by itself isn't very useful; see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) for details.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus - yes, I'm already extending my answer to add proper explanation.

Comment: But declaring the type as `List<? super Base>` makes no sense when you're assigning an `ArrayList<Base>` to it right there. Wildcards are for when you don't know the exact type parameter because it's being provided from elsewhere.

Comment: @Bozho, yeah, I see it, your update and my comment were two seconds apart from each other. I still think it's a good link, though, so I'm going to leave it there.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus - yes, absolutely. +1 for the link

Comment: thanks Bozho, I thought "When a method reads/iterates over elements in a collection then it is a consumer, when it add to a collections then it is a producer." but it seems from your answer it should be reverse "adding to a collection is consumer,  and reading from a collection is a producer"

Comment: I think "a list that holds instances of any subclass of `Base` (or `Base` itself)" describes `List<Base>` more than `List<? extends Base>`. `List<? extends Base>` is more like "a list that holds instances of one specific but unknown subtype of `Base` (which may be `Base` itself)".

Answer (score 1):

Just make it

```
List<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();
```

You shouldn't use wildcards when you know the actual type... just when you're being provided with something with an unknown type.

In such cases, `? extends Base` means that the `List` is only allowed to contain some specific subtype of `Base`, but you don't know which subtype that is. Because of that, you can't add anything but `null` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading `?` as something:

```
List<? extends Base>
```

This is "`List` of something that extends `Base`". So it is clear that you cannot add a `Base` (just as you cannot add an `Object` to a `List<String>` even when `String` extends `Object`.

What you can do in your case is:

```
List<? super Base>
```

This is "`List` of something that is extended by `Base`". So you can add a `Base` there (just as you can add a `String` to a `List<Object>`, because `Object` is extended by `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a design of Java Generics. The wildcard `? extends Base` is compiled to mean that the collection reference can point to a collection object that can hold any ( and all ) types that extend Base.You can write like this as well :

```
List<? extends Base> _listBaseSubtypes = new ArrayList<Derived>();
```

Now , with the above line , if you think about it , the below will be obviously an error :

```
        _listBaseSubtypes.add(new Base());
```

I think Java designers decided to allow the first line of code as valid. In order to avoid the runtime error that the second line of code can cause , it is caught at compile time.

Having said that , the question that comes to mind is : What type of object should be allowed to be added into the collection , given the fact that the actual collection object can be a collection of 'any' derived type  ?

Because you can derive as many types as you want , and there cannot be found a single type that is assignment compatible with the type held in the actual collection object ( remember , the collection object could be declared to hold 'any' derived type ) , the simple answer to the question is : None. So , you cannot add any object into the collection through the add interface, because for any object that you may try passing into the add method , there will be complier objection raised on the reason that this type is not compatible with the type that the actual collection object holds.